# Caching Videos in Safari using Workbox

Tags: safari, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I have a Vue.js app which i'm currently using workbox to cache so it works offline. However, videos don't seem to work in Safari.

I've researched and all signs point to this:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes#cached-av

but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Here's my code as it stands:

**Webpack**

```
configureWebpack: {
plugins: [
  new InjectManifest({
    swSrc: './src/sw.js',
    swDest: "sw.js",
    maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 5000000000
  })
]}
```

**sw.js (service worker)**

```
import { skipWaiting, clientsClaim } from "workbox-core";
import { precacheAndRoute } from "workbox-precaching";
import { registerRoute } from "workbox-routing";
import { CacheFirst } from "workbox-strategies";
import { CacheableResponsePlugin } from "workbox-cacheable-response";
import { RangeRequestsPlugin } from "workbox-range-requests";

registerRoute(
  ({ url }) => url.pathname.endsWith(".mp4"),
  new CacheFirst({
    plugins: [
      new CacheableResponsePlugin({ statuses: [200] }),
      new RangeRequestsPlugin()
    ]
  })
);

skipWaiting();
clientsClaim();
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised as I was precaching I had to specify what cache to use in the CacheFirst object, as the default is set to the runtime cache. To do this, I imported cacheNames from workbox-core

```
import { skipWaiting, clientsClaim, cacheNames } from "workbox-core";
```

Then I set the precache name

```
const precacheCacheName = cacheNames.precache;
```

Then in when setting up the CacheFirst object I specified the name as such:

```
  new CacheFirst({
    cacheName: precacheCacheName,
```

Here's the complete code:

```
import { skipWaiting, clientsClaim, cacheNames } from "workbox-core";
import { precacheAndRoute } from "workbox-precaching";
import { registerRoute } from "workbox-routing";
import { CacheFirst } from "workbox-strategies";
import { CacheableResponsePlugin } from "workbox-cacheable-response";
import { RangeRequestsPlugin } from "workbox-range-requests";

const precacheCacheName = cacheNames.precache;

registerRoute(
  ({ url }) => url.pathname.endsWith(".mp4"),
  new CacheFirst({
    cacheName: precacheCacheName,
    matchOptions: { ignoreSearch: true },
    plugins: [
      new CacheableResponsePlugin({ statuses: [200] }),
      new RangeRequestsPlugin()
    ]
  })
);

skipWaiting();
clientsClaim();
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because your `.mp4` files have a `__WB_MANIFEST` URL query parameter appended to them in the cache, since they need to be versioned by Workbox's precaching logic.

A quick solution would be to set [`matchOptions`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/v5/packages/workbox-strategies/CacheFirst.mjs#L44) when constructing the strategy:

```
new CacheFirst({
  matchOptions: { ignoreSearch: true },
  plugins: [
    new CacheableResponsePlugin({ statuses: [200] }),
    new RangeRequestsPlugin()
  ]
})
```

Comment: That was a really good idea! But unfortunately it wasn't it wholly. But it was great to know and use. I just had to set the cache it was using - which seems rather obvious in hindsight.